# Is it possible to count by using the count function within across()?

Tags: r, dplyr, count, across

Hello R and tidyverse wizards,

I try to count the rows of the starwars data set to know how many observations we get with the variables "height" and "mass"
.
I managed to get it with this code:

```
library(tidyverse)

starwars %>%
  select(height, mass) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = c(height, mass),
                   list(obs = ~ n(),
                        mean = mean,
                        sd = sd))) %>%
  View()
```

I would like to replace the `obs = ~ n()` by the `count` function and tried this version:

```
library(tidyverse)

starwars %>%
  select(height, mass) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = c(height, mass),
                   list(obs = count,
                        mean = mean,
                        sd = sd))) %>%
  View()
```

but it was too simple to work, classic :p

I had this error message --> Error in View : Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`

And when I got rid of the View() function, I had another error message --> Error in `summarise()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `height_obs`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

So, I got two questions:

- could someone please explain why the code worked with `~ n()` but not with `count`?
- is it possible to use the `count` function instead of `~ n()` in that case?

Sorry if it is a dumb question but I just try to understand the `across` and the `count` functions by playing with it.

Comment: The first argument to `count` is a `data.frame`. All of the functions inside your `across`-list will see one vector at a time, never a frame.

Answer (score 2):

In the function description it says that "`df %>% count(a, b)` is roughly equivalent to `df %>% group_by(a, b) %>% summarise(n = n())`", so I assume that using `count()` within `across` results in something like a double summarize-command, hence the use in favor of `n()`.

Edit: Here you find the solution in the comment by G. Grothendieck
[What is the difference between n() and count() in R? When should one favour the use of either or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67418568/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-count-in-r-when-should-one-favour-the)

- `n()` returns a number
- `count()` returns a dataframe

Comment: Your point about the output is salient, and your explanation is correct, I think it's also critical to indicate that the arguments are different: `count` expects a frame, but all of the `across`-list functions will only see one vector at a time. Just like `count(1:10)` will not work by itself, it won't work inside `across`.

Comment: Ah, I did not understand the double summarize-command thing, thank you. So it is not possible to use the ```count``` function inside the ```summarise``` function. I was trying to get rid of that ```~n()``` which looks weird compared to the ```mean``` and ```sd``` functions.

Answer (score 2):

`count()` takes a dataframe as its first argument. It then returns counts for columns within that dataframe, passed as additional arguments. e.g.,

```
library(dplyr)

count(starwars, mass, height)
```

When you put `count()` inside `across()`, it passes columns to `count()` *without* including the dataframe as the first argument. Equivalent to if you ran,

```
count(starwars$mass, starwars$height)
```

Because `count()` expects a dataframe as the first argument, it throws an error.

`n()`, on the other hand, doesn’t take any arguments, and simply counts rows in the current environment (or group). You have to include the `~`, as otherwise it will try passing each column to `n()`, which causes an error since `n()` doesn’t expect arguments.

Comment: Thank you very much, I now better understand the difference between ```count``` and ```n()```.